# Problema con FloatingActionButton

Tags: android, kotlin, botón, app

necesito ayuda con este FloatingActionButton, al momento de iniciar la activity no hay problema, es decir el floating esta en pantalla y los otros floating estan modo invisible y no se pueden activar tocandolos, al estar invisibles.
El problema esta la primera vez que activas el Floating, entonces los botones que estan invisibles aparecen y cuando los tocas llaman a la funcion y hacen lo que tienen que hacer, luego, cuando volves a tocar el floating para que se vuelvan a hacer invisibles, si tocas la pantalla siguen activos y quiero que al volver hacer invisible, tambien se vuelvan a ocultar las funciones.
Muchas gracias de antemano!!
Codigo kotlin:

```
var isOpen = false
fabbotonprincipal.setOnClickListener {
        if (isOpen){
            idfabnotas.startAnimation(fabClose)
            idfabcalendario.startAnimation(fabClose)
            fabbotonprincipal.startAnimation(fabRClockwise)
            idweb.startAnimation(fabClose)
            textView7.startAnimation(fabClose)
            textView6.startAnimation(fabClose)
            textView8.startAnimation(fabClose)
            idfabnotas.isInvisible
            idfabcalendario.isInvisible
            idweb.isInvisible
            isOpen = false

        } else {
            idfabnotas.startAnimation(fabOpen)
            idfabcalendario.startAnimation(fabOpen)
            idweb.startAnimation(fabOpen)
            fabbotonprincipal.startAnimation(fabRAntiClockwise)
            textView7.startAnimation(fabOpen)
            textView6.startAnimation(fabOpen)
            textView8.startAnimation(fabOpen)
            
            idfabnotas.setOnClickListener {
                val intent = Intent(this, notas::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
            }

            idfabcalendario.setOnClickListener {
                val intent = Intent(this, calendario::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
            }

            idweb.setOnClickListener {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Texto del Toast", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
            isOpen = true
        }
```

Muestra de la pantalla:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo con la [documentación de Material Design](https://material.io/components/buttons-floating-action-button/android#using-fabs), deberías poder ocultar e inhabilitar el botón llamando a fab.hide()

```
if (isOpen){
        idfabnotas.startAnimation(fabClose)
        idfabcalendario.startAnimation(fabClose)
        fabbotonprincipal.startAnimation(fabRClockwise)
        idweb.startAnimation(fabClose)
        textView7.startAnimation(fabClose)
        textView6.startAnimation(fabClose)
        textView8.startAnimation(fabClose)
        idfabnotas.hide()
        idfabcalendario.hide()
        idweb.hide()
        isOpen = false

    }
```

También te recomiendo setear los OnClickListener fuera del onClickListener del botón principal, ya que cada que el usuario hace clic en el primer botón estás creando nuevos listeners para los demás botones y esto puede afectar el rendimiento de tu app.

```
fabbotonprincipal.setOnClickListener {
...
}

idfabnotas.setOnClickListener {
    val intent = Intent(this, notas::class.java)
    startActivity(intent)
}

idfabcalendario.setOnClickListener {
    val intent = Intent(this, calendario::class.java)
    startActivity(intent)
}

idweb.setOnClickListener {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Texto del Toast", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
}
```

Espero que te sirva

Comment: Hola muchas gracias por tu ayuda!!! hice los cambios, pero no funciona :(
puse las llamadas fuera del if y puse el hide pero cuando ocultas los botones y haces click en el espacio donde esta el boton te lleva a la activity, como que la invisibilidad funciona pero el boton sigue llamando al activity aun estando en invisible